# Can the url of the remote be included in the output of `git for-each-ref` command?

Tags: bash, git-remote, git-log

I am writing to a script to list all the git repositories on my system, their branches, and the latest commits on the system. So I have created this script prints out the following.

`directory, branch(ref), date, commit hash, date, commit message, ref (again)`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
for directory in `ls -d $1/*/`; do
  # echo "$directory : $directory.git"
  if [[ -d $directory/.git ]] ; then
      # filter=/refs/heads
      filter=''
      for branch in $(git -C $directory for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' $filter); do
          echo $directory : $branch :  "$(git -C $directory log -n 1 --oneline  --pretty=format:'%Cred%h - %C(yellow)%ai - %C(green)%s %C(reset) %gD' $branch)" : $(echo $branch | rev | cut -d\/ -f-1 | rev)
      done
  fi
done
```

What I don't have is the repository URLs for the remotes. Can the remote's URL be printed as part of the output of `git for-each-ref` command?

I guess I could use `git remote -C $directory -v` to list the remotes for the repository into a lookup list which I would use for each value of `xxxxx` in `refs/remotes/xxxxx` into a variable which would be added to the `echo` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git for-each-ref` to generate an arbitrary script that will later be evaluated with `eval`. Adapting to your case the longest of the [examples from the documentation on `git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_examples), I arrived at the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
for directory in "$1"/*/ ; do
  # echo "$directory : $directory.git"
  if [[ -d $directory/.git ]] ; then
      # filter=/refs/heads
      filter=''
      fmt="
           dir=$directory"'
           ref=%(refname)
           refshort=%(refname:short)
           h=%(objectname:short)
           date=%(authordate:iso)
           subj=%(subject)

           printf "%s : %s : %s - %s - %s : %s" "$dir" "$ref" %(color:red)"$h" %(color:yellow)"$date" %(color:green)"$subj" %(color:reset)"$refshort"
           if [[ $ref == refs/remotes/* ]]
           then
               remotename="${ref#refs/remotes/}"
               remotename="${remotename%%/*}"
               printf " : %s" "$(git -C "$dir" remote get-url "$remotename")"
           fi
           printf "\n"
        '

        eval="$(git -C $directory for-each-ref --shell --format="$fmt" $filter)"
        eval "$eval"
  fi
done
```

Note that I got rid of the `git log` from your implementation, but as a result I also dropped the `%gD` field, since I didn't quite well understand what it meant, and couldn't find how to obtain it inside `git-for-each-ref`. Besides, I changed the way of obtaining the short ref from the full ref; my implementation is not equivalent yours, but produces unambiguous results).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I use `git log -n 1 ` to ensure only the latest commit on each branch is returned. How does your command achieve that, it is built in? How does the `remotename="${ref#refs/remotes/}";remotename="${remotename%%/*}"` work? It is a bit of bash I don't understand. The question is about as much as bash at it was about git, a note that was in the original draft.

Comment: @vfclists `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%%word}` are forms of shell parameter expansion that remove the specified pattern respectively from the beginning and the trailing portions of the variable's value.  For more details read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: @vfclists *I use git log -n 1 to ensure only the latest commit on each branch is returned. How does your command achieve that, it is built in?* Since you are interested in just the latest commit on each branch (i.e. the tip of the branch), you can just translate the symbolic name of the branch to the hash of the commit it refers to. In `git for-each-ref` it can be obtained as `%(objectname)`.

Comment: Does this mean that the objectname refers to the latest commit on the branch, ie `branchname = latest commit` or `refs/heads/xxxxx` refers to latest commit?

Comment: @vfclists Yes, exactly